# Iterate through a class of specific div which is inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a 2 divs with with inner controls having class name '.news-member-apps'. on same page. Now, i want to Loop through the class name of specific div say i want to loop through #div1 which has class name '.news-member-apps' and not the other #div2. and get the value.

Note: Here i am copying the previous page DIV content to current page div i.e eg: in #PrevSelectedNews and looping through it.

```
var id = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenFieldNewsID.ClientID%>');
    $('#PrevSelectedNews').load("/Default.aspx #ScrollerDiv", function () {
                alert(id.value);
                alert('Load was performed.' + $('#PrevSelectedNews'));
               $(".news-member-apps").each(function (k) {
                    var NEWSID = $(this).attr("newsid");
                    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
                    if (NEWSID == id.value) {

                        $("#" + ID).appendTo("#SelectedNews");
                       alert($("#" + ID) + "Found! Appending");

                   }

               });

            });
```

The #PrevSelectedNews contains all news items from previous page. *Now just i want to loop through #PrevSelectedNews only where inner controls class has name '.news-member-apps'. If the HiddenFiledNewID.value matched with any of the control having class name 'PrevSelectedNews' then get the id of foind control.*
Help Appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Won't this simply work? `$('#PrevSelectedNews .news-member-apps').each(function(i, obj) {
    //do stuff
});`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this selector:

```
$('#PrevSelectedNews').find('.news-member-apps').each(function() { 
    // this - reference to each .news-member-apps item
})
```

It finds element with ID 'PrevSelectedNews' and than iterates through child elements with class 'news-member-apps'.

JQuery selector docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: sorry @Andrei Mikhalevich this selected the contents of another div too...i need the div content of #PrevSelectedNews only..!

Comment: Try this: $('#PrevSelectedNews').find('.news-member-apps').each(...)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var id = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenFieldNewsID.ClientID%>');
$('#PrevSelectedNews').load("/Default.aspx #ScrollerDiv", function() {
    $(".news-member-apps", this).filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr("newsid") == id.value
    }).each(function(k) {
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id")).appendTo("#SelectedNews");
    });
});
```